# Who is this Asian figure?

Tags: identification, asia

I’m looking for help in identifying this figure. I bought this box at a thrift store a few years back because it was silver and because it looked nice. Every once in a while, curiosity hits me as I look at it and wonder who the figure on the top is. There is no text or trademark on the box, only a very small line of text at the bottom that says “Silver .925”

[image: Small, silver, and oval box with Asian figure inscribed on porcelain.]

The figure looks Asian, and it’s art style is that of Chinese porcelain I’ve seen in stores. The porcelain looks like it has been taken from a larger picture, since there is a small bit of paint at the left side that is abruptly cut off. I’m very curious as to who this figure is, as he seems very iconic, but my historical knowledge is not so good. He’s got what seems to be a sword on his back, a flag (possibly) in his left hand, and a long cloak-like outfit. Somewhat iconic hat, expression, and outfit.

Any ideas would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance. =D

Comment: If the person is supposed to be a scholar or government official instead of a solider, the thing on his back could be the handle of a scroll hidden behind him, and not the handle of a sword..

Comment: Looks a bit like common Confucius drawings/statues.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a figure of Lu Dongbin (also spelled Lu Tung-Pin), one of the Eight Immortals of Taoism.

Quoted from [Learn Religions](https://www.learnreligions.com/taoist-immortal-lu-dongbin-lu-tung-pin-an-introduction-3182609):

> **Lu Dongbin’s emblem is the magic two-edged sword**, which dispels evil spirits, and gives him the power of invisibility. He’s also frequently shown **carrying a fly-whisk** and **is dressed and honored as a scholar**. He’s known for being a “ladies’ man” and for being prone to bouts of drunkenness.

Comment: Thank you very much ThirstforKnowledge! I’m astounded that you figured it out.